# Layover in San Francisco

Tags: san-francisco

We are passing through San Francisco Airport on December 2, 2018. We arrive at 4:30 AM and depart at 6:45 PM. Is is enough time to visit the Golden Gate bridge and places around?

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. The airport is only 30 minutes from the Golden Gate, which is on the other side of San Francisco itself, so you can either hire a car for flexibility to see the Golden Gate National Recreation Area and other outlying areas, or use public transport.

You can visit key locations in SF itself such as Pier 39, Lafayette Park, Haight- Ashbury, ride a trolley car, get to the Golden Gate and still have time.

Comment: Ok thank for answer :) It's just shame we arrive so early in the morning, or maybe it's advantage, we'll see :)

Comment: Pop your bags in left luggage and go grab a nice breakfast before checking out the city :-)

Comment: @Milan An advantage, definitely. Getting into the city is a lot easier *before* the morning rush.

Comment: @Sneftel December 2 is a Sunday, but it is true that if the OP were attempting this during weekday rush hour, it could easily take an hour from the airport to the Presidio.